# Pyramid pattern problem with O(n) Time Complexity?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Recently, I saw someone asking for a solution to print a `'*'` pyramid pattern in *N* lines using just single `while` loop in a Facebook group.

I found that most of the answers in that post are using syntactic sugar of the languages (like `'*'*N;`) or using built-in method like `.charAt()`, for example, which is somewhat technically looping inside that syntax or method I assume?

How we can calculate the time complexity when it has only 1 loop which appears in the code? Will it counted to be *O(N)* time complexity?

And what if we use only

1. While loop
2. Integer variable
3. Standard IO
4. If else condition

To print the pattern (if it's possible?)

The standard output (like `printf()`) would always takes *N* x *N* time to print the pattern including `'*'` star symbol and `' '` space character in each line which would be *theta(N^2)* time complexity if I understand it correctly?

Or are there other approaches to print the pattern using just *O(N)* or *theta(N)*?

Or have I just absolutely missed the concept about looping and time complexity?

Comment: link to the fb post?

Comment: naively it would be `O(N^2)` ... however depending on what the `N` is there might be also considered as `O(N)` for example by using fast memory transfer or DMA for smaller N might be considered `O(1)`  like using direct VRAM access in VGA text mode + `memset` ... or `rep stosw` ... for example in mode 3 the screen is `80x25` so pyramid might have line length max 80x2 bytes and that is not much so the transfer times between n=1 and n=80 might be too small or non measurable ...depending on the transfer method used

Comment: *"for smaller N might be considered O(1)"* - this is meaningless. What happens for small n has nothing to do with Big O notation.

Comment: The simple answer is that you want to print O(n^2) characters, so there is no way you are ever going to do that in less time than O(n^2).

Comment: Can anyone please open this question?

Comment: @kaya3 check this out ;-) 
https://mystb.in/HuntingtonBethTelecommunications.c

Comment: @Ava the question is on a private Facebook page. And I have no matter with the question which it just requires you to print pyramid pattern with just single While loop (you can use For loop or whatever built-in method or syntactic sugar of that particular language). The topic here is my curiosity about time complexity if we write the code in any approach that meet the criteria above (Single while loop).

Comment: the above code should also work with while loop I guess.

Comment: @Ava What about it? Do you think it runs in O(n) time for some reason? Clearly it runs in O(n^2) time.

Comment: @kaya3 how is it running in O(N^2) time? Can you please explain?

Comment: @Ava Simple; your `size` variable is defined as a quadratic function of `n`, and then you loop that many times. And then you call `printf` on a string of quadratic length, which also takes quadratic time. It is simply impossible to print a quadratic number of characters in linear time.

Comment: @kaya3 nope. That's not how it works. Please go through this article. https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-o-notation

Comment: @Ava I don't know what to tell you other than that you are completely wrong for the reasons I have explained.

Comment: @Ava Your code is printing a right-angled triangle not a pyramid.

Comment: You can adjust the spaces accordingly. Take it as your hw ;-)

Comment: @kaya3 I got it dw. It's `O(n^2)` and you're right.

Comment: @Ava I think the 'size' variable of your code is obviously O(n^2) since it is (n^2 + 3n)/2 (I know it is significantly lower than just n^2) but in Big O it is considered to be O(n^2). and its iteration is not different from a generic nested loop solution.

Comment: when pyramid pattern always has n characters in each line (including space and star). I think the iteration would be increased. And yeah it still O(N^2)

Comment: yes and it is not actually possible to print this pattern in `O(n)` time as kaya3 mentioned. But if you look it from the other way, I think it could be a very good challenge to print the star pattern without using nested loops or using only single loop. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `n` is the height or width of the pyramid, the number of briks/`*`s will be `O(n^2)`. The area of a triangle is `(height*width) / 2` (and therefore `O(n^2)` where `n` is either height or width), and fancy programming cannot change that.

If, however, `n` is not defined, then you can define it as the number of characters -- and then you can do the following with a single loop

```js
/**
 * builds an asterisk pyramid with a single loop
 * n = number of characters in the pyramid, including spaces & line-breaks
 * (use n = 2*o*o, such as 32 (o=4 layers), if you want pretty pyramids)
 */
function pyramid(n) {
   let output = [];
   let ri = 0;                            // current position in row
   let nr = 1;                            // asterisks in next row; always odd
   let lr = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(2*n+1))-1; // longest row
   for (let i=0; i<n; i++) {
     if (ri >= lr) {                
        output.push("\n");         // output end-of-row
        nr += 2;                   // each row has one extra `*` on each side
        ri = 0;
     } else if (ri >= ((lr - nr)/2) && ri < (lr - (lr - nr)/2)) {
        output.push("*");          // output actual brick
        ri ++;
     } else {
        output.push(".");          // output space
        ri ++;
     }
   } 
   return output.join("");
}

// test with 1 to 4 layers
for (let i=1; i<5; i++) {
  let n = (2*i)*i;
  console.log(n + "\n" + pyramid(n));
}
```

Comment: The OP defined N as the number of lines in the pattern.